# How should I insert an image in a beamer file?

Tags: beamer, graphics

I know how to make a presentation by tex;
but I don't know how to insert an image?

What is the code of inserting an image?

Comment: `\includegraphics{name}`

Comment: May I suggest you this book? http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/